# How to remove password from the Principal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My goal is to remove Password from the `Principal`.

note: By default, Spring Security did not store Password in Principal. I override `UserDetailsService` to add more info such as `name`, `id`, `channelIds`. However, my implementation stores the password in `Principal`, which I believe is bad.

You can get the Principal by creating a GET endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class UserDetailsController {
  @GetMapping("/userdetails")
  public Principal getUserDetails(Principal user) {
    return user;
  }
}
```

This is my implementation to get more info e.g `name`, `id`, `channelIds`, etc.

```
@RestController
public class UserDetailsController {
  // TODO: hide password.
  @GetMapping("/userdetails")
  public MyUserDetails getUserDetails(@CurrentSecurityContext(expression = "authentication.principal") Object user) {
    return (MyUserDetails) user;
  }
}
```

My expected result is that the password is null.

My actual result is that the password is not null. e.g. password in database is encrypted `ewaejovra`, the password stored in Principal will be `ewaejovra`.

#### This is my implementation

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  ...
}
```

MyUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  private final UserMapper userMapper;

  public MyUserDetailsService(UserMapper userMapper) {
    this.userMapper = userMapper;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<UserModel> user = userMapper.getUser(s);

    user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username Not Found: " + s)); // TODO: who receives the Exception?

    return user.map(MyUserDetails::new).get();
  }
}
```

MyUserDetails.java

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

  private final String userId;

  private final String username;
  private String password;
  private final boolean active;
  private final Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

  public MyUserDetails(UserModel user) {
    this.userId = user.getId();

    this.username = user.getUser();
    this.password = user.getPassword();
    this.active = user.getActive();

    this.authorities = Set.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return active;
  }

  public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }
}
```

Comment: one way, you can simply set password as null before returning the user from GET endpoint..

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove the password from the principle object, you can avoid sending it on the request but once sent it will be picked up by the principle in order to use it in Spring Security.

This really depend on the way you do security, for example if user must pass his creds (`username` + `password`) on each request to access secured resources you will end up having the password always in principle which makes sense at the end password is just some string needed for security.

If on the other hand you use some JWT access token the consumer receives once he perform a successful login, and then he would exchange it with your server to access secured resources at that style of security you would see the `password` once in the `principle` object at the first time user logs in but after that only piece of data you would see in the principle object is the access token
check https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-security-json-web-tokenjwt-hello-world for more info

Comment: I use session, so for every request I only send the session id either in Cookie or in headers. According to what you said, I will only see the password once in the `Principle` object, but when I send a request to GET `/userdetails`, the `Password`'s key is not null. Which is worrying since somehow it does not follow the Spring Security design.

Comment: I also checked the link you sent to me and I am looking for the `JwtUserDetailsService`, I think the writer forget to reference it. Do you have the repository link that I can check?

Comment: when you do a get against userdetails you should not just serialise the Principal, you should serialise a curated userdetails object, or annotate the getter with @JsonIgnore so that jackson ignores that field